# Play 2.6 Inject JPAApi error "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit"

Tags: playframework-2.6

I use Ebean in my play 2.6.15 app. But I didn't find "getSingleResult" function in ebean. And I'm try use JPAApi for it. When controller try to inject JPAApi I receive a error `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit`

**controllers.PublicController.java**

```
public class PublicController extends Controller {

    @Inject
    public PublicController(JPAApi apaApi) {}

}
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val server = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin, PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += guice,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
      javaJpa,
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.3.1.Final"
  ),
  fork in run := true
)
```

**/conf/META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      ...
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**application.conf**

```
db {
  default {
    driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jndiName = DefaultDS
    url = "***"
    username = "***"
    password = "***"
    hikaricp {
      minimumIdle = ${fixedConnectionPool}
      maximumPoolSize = ${fixedConnectionPool}
    }
  }
}
jpa.default = defaultPersistenceUnit
```

I've checked all but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is resolved. was a problem with models linked, is not correct OneToMany and ManyToOne links